# how to dynamically name a form element with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm scripting an html form inside a PHP. The form is shown as a table. Every row is a 'set' of passed items that will be gathered in a **$_POST** double array where the first id is the table *ROW*, and the second identifier is the *COLUMNS*, actually the variables of the form.

Here is an example.

```
<?php
echo '<form><table>';
for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
echo '
   <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="data[',$i,'][element1]></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="data[',$i,'][element2]></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="data[',$i,'][element3]></td>
       ...
       <td><input type="text" name="data[',$i,'][elementN]></td>
   </tr>';
}
echo '</table></form>';
?>
```

The "gathering" part of the script simply is:

```
$myFormInformation = $_REQUEST['data'];
```

and shows the content like this:

```
data[1][element1] = element 1-1
data[1][element2] = element 1-2
...
data[1][elementN] = element 1-N
..
data[2][element1] = element 2-1
...
data[2][elementN] = element 2-N
... ... ... 
data[10][elementN] = element 10-N
```

I rendered the idea...and it perfectly works. However I don't want to have all teh 10 rows shown for input, but, instead, grant the user to add rows if needed.

I found this javascript snippet to add rows, however the problem is that I don't know how to pass the **ROW ID** dynamically to allow my $_REQUEST part of code to work. At this moment in fact the **$_REQUEST** gets only one row.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow() {
        var referenceNodes = document.getElementById("flightsTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
            //-2 because last row is button row
            var referenceNode = referenceNodes[referenceNodes.length - 1];
            var newNode = referenceNode.cloneNode(true);
            referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
        }
        document.getElementById("addNewRow").onclick = addRow;
</script>
```

obviously there is a button with **id=addNewRow** to launch the javascript.

How can I pass a "counter" from the javascript to the forms element in order to have each new row increase it's **name="data[i][elementX]"**.

I can accept other ways to do the job done, if easier...

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the `td` elements and then find the input. Setting the `name` attribute as you please.

Something like this:

```
function addRow() {
    var referenceNodes = document.getElementById("flightsTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    //-2 because last row is button row
    var referenceNode = referenceNodes[referenceNodes.length - 1];
    var newNode = referenceNode.cloneNode(true);

    // get the next count for the new row.
    var dataCount = referenceNodes.length + 1;

    // loop the cells.
    var cells = newNode.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];

        // get the input (assuming only one).
        var input = cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

        // set the name property.
        input.name = "data['" + dataCount + "'][element" + (i + 1) + "]";
    }

    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7zytz1c/)

Comment: Thank you musefan, that's an interesting solution and it works. However maybe I've made a too simple example.

In fact the elements are not called element1, 2, ..., but each one has its own name (date, name, surname, etc), so I should change only a part of the complete element name.
And not all the inputs are "input" cells, but there are textarea, select and checkboxes too.

I can somehow modify the structure of the form, but if there is a simpler way to achieve the result I would like to not touch so heavily the form.

Anyway I'll give a try.

Comment: finally I made it. however I removed the loop and sistematically named each cell because of the different elements type (input or select) and names...it is not elegant or stylish but it works. thank you for the hint!